# Refactoring test with shoulda, the minitest way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest, shoulda

I was browsing shoulda matchers and context in order to refactor some text and make them more coincise and readable, but thorough, the documentation I could not find how to test this in specific:

(I'm following Hartl tutorial, and **I'm trying to refactor in the Minitest way, not Rspec**)

[micropost_model](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_6th_ed/blob/master/app/models/micropost.rb)

`default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }`

`has_one_attached :image`

&

```
validates :image,   content_type: { in: %w[image/jpeg image/gif image/png],
                                      message: 'must be a valid image format' },
                    size: { less_than: 5.megabytes,
                            strong textmessage: 'should be less than 5MB' }
```

this:

[user_test](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_6th_ed/blob/master/test/models/user_test.rb)

[user_model](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_6th_ed/blob/master/app/models/user.rb)

`attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token`

```
before_save   :downcase_email
before_create :create_activation_digest
```

this:

[routes](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_6th_ed/blob/master/config/routes.rb)

```
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: %i[new create edit update]
  resources :microposts,          only: %i[create destroy]
  resources :relationships,       only: %i[create destroy]
```

Comment: Hartl's rails tutorial is a pretty good guide at how to never write a test. Really the are godawful. Especially the carpet bombing validation tests. What exactly is the behavior that you are trying to test? Please include the code under test and the test itself in the question body itself as links can and will break.

Comment: In this specific instance the test just sucks since the whole arrange part of the test is buried in the fixtures file. Any refactoring should really start with arrange, act, assert not just using shoulda to put makeup on the pig.

Comment: @max, I'm not new to rails, but I was following his tutorial in order to learn  how to write test actually, but then I found about Shoulda, and I think it's more coincise and readable, Just for example, how do you test with Shoulda in the Minitest way the route's resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general here are the ways you can test the pieces you've posted:

- shoulda-matchers will [soon](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/pull/1194) have a `have_one_attached` matcher you can use to test `has_one_attached`.
- The validations you posted for Micropost come from Paperclip and [Paperclip provides matchers you can use in your tests](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Shoulda/Matchers).
- You can use the validation matchers in Shoulda in place of the first several tests in `user_test` — for instance, `should validate_presence_of(:email)`, `should validate_length_of(:email).is_at_most(255)`, etc.
- Shoulda doesn't provide any facility to test authentication- or callback-related code — you will have to take a look at what your User model is doing and write tests around the logic manually. Judging by the code snippet you posted, this would probably consist of making an instance of your model, setting some attributes, saving the model, and asserting that certain attributes are set.
- There is a way to test routes using Shoulda using the [`route`](http://matchers.shoulda.io/docs/v4.3.0/Shoulda/Matchers/ActionController.html#route-instance_method). I will say about this that you will probably get better mileage per test in writing an integration or system test which exercises the functionality that is accessible via the route rather than test the route directly. But at least that matcher is there should you want that level of granularity.

Hope that helps — let me know if you need more help.